# Qt cross-compile Raspi3 - fatal error: unistd.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am following a guide `wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi_Beginners_Guide` and when it comes to building Qtbase I run a command `make` and get following error:

http://pastebin.com/a2cXFGbC

And output of `locate unistd.h`:

http://pastebin.com/F656G0eG

Some details: PC Debian Jessie, Raspberry Pi 3, SD card with installed Raspbian (as in guide).

Answer (score 0):

My configre command line (disregard all sysroot/prefix/hostprefix/extprefix options):

`./configure -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi2-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot "$R" -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -make libs -make tools -prefix /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5 -extprefix /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5 -hostprefix /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5`

(notice pi2, and there is probably a config for pi3 too)

And a patch to a file in qtbase (change to match your gcc version and path):

```
---------------- mkspecs/devices/linux-rasp-pi2-g++/qmake.conf ----------------
index 9be3f40..fcef488 100644
@@ -11,11 +11,11 @@ QMAKE_INCDIR_EGL        = $$[QT_SYSROOT]/opt/vc/include \
                           $$[QT_SYSROOT]/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads \
                           $$[QT_SYSROOT]/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux
 QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL_ES2 = $${QMAKE_INCDIR_EGL}

 QMAKE_LIBS_EGL          = -lEGL -lGLESv2
-QMAKE_CFLAGS += -march=armv7-a -marm -mthumb-interwork -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mtune=cortex-a7 -mabi=aapcs-linux
+QMAKE_CFLAGS += -march=armv7-a -marm -mthumb-interwork -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mtune=cortex-a7 -mabi=aapcs-linux -I$$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/include/c++/4.9/ -I$$[QT_SYSROOT]/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/c++/4.9
 QMAKE_CXXFLAGS          = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS

 DISTRO_OPTS += hard-float

 # Preferred eglfs backend
```